# MySQL Group By to display latest result

Tags: mysql, wordpress, greatest-n-per-group, custom-post-type

I'm trying to query MySQL to ORDER then GROUP... it's a question that comes up a lot here and I found an answer that seemed relevant to me: [Getting a MySQL group by query to display the row in that group with the highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589508/getting-a-mysql-group-by-query-to-display-the-row-in-that-group-with-the-highest)

However I'm finding that it is still not ordering before doing the grouping.

Specifically what I'm trying to do is use Wordpress custom post types to group by a meta data field called 'date', ordered by the post date.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    `ID`, `date`, `post_date`, `date_rank`
FROM (
        SELECT
            `Post`.`ID`,
            `Post`.`post_date`,
            `PostData`.`meta_value` AS `date`,
            CASE
                WHEN @data_date = `PostData`.`meta_value` THEN @rowum := @rownum + 1
                ELSE @rownum := 1
            END AS date_rank,
            @data_date := `PostData`.`meta_value`
        FROM
            `".$this->wpdb->posts."` AS `Post`
        JOIN 
            `".$this->wpdb->postmeta."` AS `PostData`
            ON `Post`.`ID` = `PostData`.`post_id` AND `PostData`.`meta_key` = 'date'
        JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @data_date := '') AS `vars`
        WHERE 
            `Post`.`post_type` = 'my_post_type'
            AND
            `Post`.`post_status` = 'publish'
        ORDER BY `Post`.`post_date` DESC
    ) AS `x`
WHERE date_rank = 1
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

The desired results are a post for each 'date' (this is a meta field), with the latest post for this 'date' as per the post_date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT meta_value
        FROM    postdata pd
        WHERE   pd.meta_key = 'date'
        ) pd
JOIN    post p
ON      p.id = 
        (
        SELECT  post_id
        FROM    postdata pdi
        JOIN    post pi
        ON      pi.id = pdi.post_id
        WHERE   pdi.meta_key = 'date'
                AND pdi.meta_value = pd.meta_value
        ORDER BY
                pi.post_date DESC, pi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```