# Order within group by?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

In my system, I have clients. Clients have programs. I want to display a list of clients, showing their most recent active (if it exists) program.

Thus, we have something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients AS client 
    JOIN programs AS program ON client.id=program.client_id
GROUP BY client.id
ORDER BY program.close_date=0 DESC, program.close_date DESC
```

`close_date=0` means the program isn't closed. So it will put the non-closed programs first, and then the most recently closed programs next.

Problem is, the order by doesn't work within the groups. It just kind of picks one of the programs at random. How do I resolve this?

---

Just came up with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients AS client 
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM programs AS program ORDER BY program.close_date=0 DESC, program.close_date DESC) AS program ON client.id=program.client_id
GROUP BY client.id
```

Which seems to give correct results. Is this correct, or am I just getting lucky? i.e., I've essentially sorted the table before joining on it; those results will stay sorted as it does the join, right?

---

**Solution:** I now believe this a classic [group-wise maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. Search for that if you're stuck on a similar problem. The solution involves joining the same table twice.

Comment: The ORDER BY in the sub-select should have no deterministic effect on the result.  It may happen to work with MySQL, but the SQL standard doesn't even allow it.  The key point is to ORDER BY the client.id in the main (outer query), then by any other columns you want.  You might have to say the same things in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses; it doesn't cost anything to do so.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think your alternate solution (posted above) is guaranteed to give correct results. After a `GROUP BY` is done on `client.id`, ["the server is free to choose any record from each group"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: @ubutbu: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know. I was worried that might be the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  c.*, p.*
FROM    clients AS c
JOIN    programs AS p
ON      p.id = 
        (
        SELECT  pi.id
        FROM    programs AS pi
        WHERE   pi.client_id = c.id
        ORDER BY
                pi.close_date=0 DESC, pi.close_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Thanx should go to **[@Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi)**. See his answer in a similar (but more complicated) question: **[mysql-group-by-to-display-latest-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668902/mysql-group-by-to-display-latest-result)**

---

If you update the `programs` table and set `close_date` for all records that it is zero to `close_date='9999-12-31'`, then your `ORDER BY` will be simpler (and the whole query faster with proper indexes):

```
        ORDER BY
                pi.close_date DESC
```

Comment: Ah...yeah, this join makes a lot more sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the answer I've looked everywhere for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this order by clause ...

```
ORDER BY client.id, CASE WHEN program.close_date = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, program.close_date DESC
```

Comment: I don't see how that accomplishes anything. `program.close_date=0` will evaluate to `0` or `1` already. The problem is I need to sort within the groups, the overall sorting (after grouping) is fine.

Comment: The first column listed is client.id ... that will keep your groups together.

Comment: Oh.....you should have pointed that out in your answer. Although I'm still not 100% sure what you mean by that. Putting `client.id` first will make the ordering work? Why would that make a difference?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why you are using GROUP BY in the first place ... typically GROUP BY is used when you need a SUM, COUNT, or other aggregate from the returned rows.  At any rate, ORDER BY trumps GROUP BY as far as the sorting of the rows returned.

Comment: I'm using GROUP BY because I only want to list each client once, but I want to show his most recent program data. What do you mean ORDER BY trumps GROUP BY? It looks to me like ordering is applied after grouping. I need to apply some ordering within each group so that I can retrieve only a particular program for each client. The actual ordering of the client list as a whole is a separate (non-)issue.