# Function like GROUP_CONCAT (that supports ordering) but only returns 1 result? Or like MAX but with order?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Is there a function similar to `GROUP_CONCAT` in that it supports an `ORDER BY`, but only returns 1 result?

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(x ORDER BY y LIMIT 1)
```

`MIN` and `MAX` won't work for me because I'm ordering by `y` instead of `x`.

---

**Edit2:** Found another way to write the query that involves a subquery. A lot of tables are joined twice, once for the conditions (in the subquery) and once to get the values for display since I can't pull them out of the subquery.

Comment: You should post your update as an answer...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve the `greatest-n-per-group` problem, which comes up frequently on Stack Overflow.  I've added the tag to your question, please click on it.  This has been answered many times.

Comment: You might get more help if you specify what it is you need. I can't seem to think what you want to use this for, other then the standard "group by, find row that belongs with max" problem, that is usually fixed by selecting the max and then getting the row with that max... (max could be another aggregate function ofcourse)

Comment: @Adrian: It's not a satisfactory answer. I'm looking for something better.

Comment: @Nanne: It's the same problem as my last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233757) except that solution stopped working for me. If it joins on the wrong program, it might not meet the where conditions. So I tried copying the where conditions into the "on" clause of the program join, but not all of them are applicable. I've got 20ish such lists, and I want the schema (tables + joins) to be the same for each of them so that I only have to tweak the where conditions programatically.

Comment: @ajreal: What are you referring to?

Comment: group concate with substring index

Comment: @Mark: Why did the answer to the previous solution stopped working? WHat did you change in the query?

Comment: @ypercube: Ok, it didn't exactly "stop" working, it never worked quite properly in the first place. Would work in 99% of scenarios, but there were a few cases where it would join on the wrong program, and then the client wouldn't meet all the where conditions when he should have (had it selected a different program to join on). Restructuring it such that *all* the where conditions are moved into the program join seems to be working now though.

Comment: Yes, any additional condition (about `programs`) should be added in the subquery `WHERE` clause. You can add it in the surrounding query as well but it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to do what I want, but it isn't very nice:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(x ORDER BY y),',',1)
```

And this makes the assumption that there are no other commas in `x`.