# ORDER within GROUP BY with calculated fields

Tags: mysql

I have a query that retrieves location entities within a certain radius given a latitude and longitude.

I'm now trying to adapt that query to return a list of users within a certain radius, with their most recent location alongside it. My problem is that if I GROUP BY the user id, I can't then sort the locations to only return the most recent one.

I've tried following [ypercube's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233757/order-within-group-by) on using a subquery which has got me this far:

```
SET @mylon = -1.095414;
SET @mylat = 50.79486;

SELECT  u.*, dest.*
FROM    users AS u
JOIN    locations AS dest
ON      dest.id = 
        (
        SELECT  l.id, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@mylat - abs(l.latitude)) * pi()/180/2),
                2) + COS(@mylat * pi()/180) * COS(abs(l.latitude) *
                pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@mylon - l.longitude) *
                pi()/180/2),2))) as distance
        FROM    locations AS l
        HAVING  distance < 0.5
        ORDER BY
                l.created DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

However, this returns an SQL error as I've got more than one field being returned by my subquery.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: why are you joining location with location .. where is the join criteria for users and location ??

Comment: I'm trying to get each user with only its most recent location within the radius calculated. Ideally I'd just do a normal query with GROUP BY u.id, but that doesn't let me sort the locations being grouped to only return the most recent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your subquery must return only an id that should be matched with the dest.id.
I don't see you using GROUP BY so you should replace HAVING with WHERE.
I think you can directly say WHERE (3956 * 2 * ASIN(.......) < 0.5 so that you don't put that computation in the result and leave only the id

```
SET @mylon = -1.095414;
SET @mylat = 50.79486;

SELECT  u.*, dest.*
FROM    users AS u
JOIN    locations AS dest
ON      dest.id = 
    (
    SELECT  l.id
    FROM    locations AS l
    WHERE (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@mylat - abs(l.latitude)) * pi()/180/2),
            2) + COS(@mylat * pi()/180) * COS(abs(l.latitude) *
            pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@mylon - l.longitude) *
            pi()/180/2),2)))) < 0.5
    ORDER BY
            l.created DESC
    LIMIT 1
    )
```

To return also the computation you may be able to create a temporary table like this

```
SET @mylon = -1.095414;
SET @mylat = 50.79486;

SELECT  u.*, dest.*
FROM    users AS u
JOIN    (
    SELECT  l.id, l.created, (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@mylat - abs(l.latitude)) * pi()/180/2),
        2) + COS(@mylat * pi()/180) * COS(abs(l.latitude) *
        pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@mylon - l.longitude) *
        pi()/180/2),2)))) as distance
FROM    locations  ) as location_table_tmp
ON u.id = location_table_tmp.id
ORDER BY location_table_tmp.created DESC
```

I'm not sure if the syntax is Ok, try to tweak a little bit and hope it works

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! Would there be any way of returning the distance within the result set as well?

Comment: Tweaked the syntax of the query with the temporary table a bit but it always returns "Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'". The users table definitely contains an id column. Weird!

Comment: try users.id instead of u.id. That is indeed strange

Comment: users.id has the same effect. :(