# MySQL View to do a Group by after an Order by

Tags: mysql, group-by

the "t_example" table :

```
id | date
---------------
1  | 2001-05-09
1  | 2005-11-05
1  | 2000-08-19
2  | 2010-10-30
2  | 2002-12-10
2  | 2009-07-29
3  | 2003-02-15
3  | 2012-04-20
```

I would like to create a view that returns the following result (the max date for each id):

```
id | date_id
---------------
1  | 2005-11-05
2  | 2010-10-30
3  | 2012-04-20
```

MySQL don't allow to do a subquery with order by in view, and when I use an other view for the subquery, the group by ignore the order by in the subquery.

The following query returns the expected result:

```
select id, date
from (select id, date from t_example order by id asc, date_id desc) p
group by p.id
```

But when I use it in a views it does't work:

```
view1 (subquery) : select id, date from t_example order by id asc, date_id desc;
view2 : select id, date from view1 group by view1.id;
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: `SELECT id, MAX(date) AS date_id FROM t_example GROUP BY id ;`

Comment: Search stackoverflow for this question, it's been asked many times before. Here's one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233757/order-within-group-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you

```
SELECT id, MAX(date) AS date FROM t_example GROUP BY id;
```

This is using the `AS` syntax to keep your column name succinct (otherwise it would be `MAX(date)`)

Answer (score 1):

select id,max(date)
from your_table
group by id