# Doctrine left join Many to one

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table **client** and table **client_evolution**, with OneToMany relationship. In **client_evolution** table I have 3 entries for current client. Pulling data with Left Join I get always the first entry with smallest id from **client_evolution** , what I need is the latest row. I have tried to do subselect but it didn't work.

```
->addSelect('(
    SELECT ce.id
    FROM ClientEvolution cev
    WHERE cev.client = c.id
    GROUP BY cev.client
    ORDER BY cev.id DESC) AS cevol')
```

I need more than one field from this table.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY is why you are getting only one entry per client also your SELECT is missing the client table.  This will give you all the fields between the two tables in order of client ids.  To only get the latest row for each client id, please look at [MySQL Group By to display latest result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668902/mysql-group-by-to-display-latest-result)

```
->addSelect('(
    SELECT *
    FROM ClientEvolution cev, Client c
    WHERE cev.client = c.id
    ORDER BY cev.client, cev.id DESC)')
```

Comment: Are you sure * is allowed? I am getting an error
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 479: Error: Unexpected '*'

Comment: It is allowed in MySQL, but might not be allowed in doctrine.  Just replace the * with the names of the columns you want separated by commas, such as `SELECT cev.id, c.name, c.phone, cev.note, cev.date FROM` ...